# Understand the definition of distance-regular graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am really struggling with a definition and am probably thinking too much into it. I hope someone can clear it up for me. In the following $d(x,y)$ is the smallest distance between two vertices $x$ and $y$ (by counting the edges).

A Graph is called distance-regular if for any two vertices $x$ and $y$ with $d(x,y) = k$ the number of vertices $z$ with $d(x,z) = i$ and $d(z,y) = j$ is a constant $p_{ij}^k$ (so that it only depends on the variable $k$).

I have an example where it said that the left graph is distance-regular but the right one isnt but i cant seem to see why.
[image]
I see that both graphs have diameter $3$. And for each two vertices $x,y$ i choose the number of vertices $z$ is always a constant (i always take the smallest way possible which gets me the constant). I dont see what I am missing so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a distance-regular graph, $p_{11}^1$ would tell you the number of common neighbors (vertices at distance $1$) that two adjacent vertices (vertices at distance $1$) would have.

In the graph on the left, $p_{11}^1 = 0$: any two adjacent vertices have no common neighbors.

In the graph on the right, some adjacent vertices have a common neighbor: any two vertices in the triangle at the top. All other pairs of adjacent vertices have no common neighbors. So there is no universal constant $p_{11}^1$.

---

Traditionally, $p_{11}^0$ is also supposed to be constant: for any vertices $x,y$ with $d(x,y)=0$, this is the number of vertices $z$ with $d(x,z) = d(y,z) = 1$. The only way to have $d(x,y)=0$ is to have $x=y$. So $p_{11}^0$ should tell us the number of neighbors of every vertex!

This gives us an easier way to see that the graph on the right is not distance-regular: it is not regular. Some vertices have $2$ neighbors, and some vertices have $3$ neighbors.